# Closed form for the following integral

Tags: integration, closed-form

How can I find the closed form for the following please?

$$f(r) = \frac{1}{R_x+R_C}\int^{R_x+R_c}_{0}\frac{1}{1+sr^{-4}} dr$$

where $R_x,R_c$ are constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things: the integral doesn't depend on $r$; i.e. you won't get out a function $f(r)$ because the $r$ is integrated out. Also, there is (possibly) a singularity in the range of integration if $s < 0$ so I'll assume that $s > 0$ (if $s = 0$ then the integral is trivial).

Put $T = R_x + R_c$. Then the integral is \begin{align*} I &= \frac{1}{T}\int^T_0 \frac{dr}{1+sr^{-4}} \\&= \frac{1}{T}\int^T_0 \frac{r^4 dr}{r^4 + s} \\&= \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 \left(\frac{r^4+s}{r^4 + s} - \frac{s}{r^4 + s} \right) dr \\&= 1 - \frac{s}{T} \int^T_0\frac{dr}{r^4 + s}. \end{align*} Let $r = s^{1/4}x$. Then $$I = 1 - \frac{s}{T} \int^{s^{-1/4}T}_0 \frac{s^{1/4}dx}{s(x^4+1)} = 1- \frac{1}{S}\underbrace{\int^{S}_0 \frac{dx}{x^4 +1}}_{\,\,\,\, = I^*}$$ where $S = s^{-1/4}T$. We focus on evaluating $I^*$. Now \begin{align*}\frac{1}{x^4+1} &= \frac{1}{x^4 + 2x^2 +1 - 2x^2} \\ &= \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2 - 2x^2} \\&= \frac{1}{(x^2 +1 -x\sqrt 2)(x^2+1 + x\sqrt 2)} \\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt 2} \left(\frac{\sqrt 2 + x}{x^2 + x\sqrt 2 + 1} + \frac{\sqrt 2 - x}{x^2 - x\sqrt 2 + 1}\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt 2} \left(\frac{\sqrt 2 + x}{(x+\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2} + \frac{\sqrt 2 - x}{(x-\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2}\right)\end{align*} Next $$\frac{\sqrt 2 \pm x}{(x\pm\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2} = \frac{\sqrt 2/2 \pm x}{(x\pm\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2} + \frac{\sqrt 2/2}{(x\pm\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2}.$$ Now the first term can be integrated by substitution ($u$-sub for the denominator) and the latter by trig-substitution. Indeed, \begin{align*} \int^{S}_0 \frac{\sqrt 2/2 \pm x}{(x\pm\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2}dx &= \pm \frac 1 2\log((x\pm\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2) \bigg|^{S}_0 \\&= \pm \frac 1 2\log(x^2 \pm x\sqrt2 + 1) \bigg|^{S}_0 \\ &= \pm \frac 1 2\log(S^2 \pm S\sqrt2 + 1)\end{align*} and \begin{align*} \int^S_0 \frac{\sqrt 2/2}{(x\pm\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1/2}dx &= \int^S_0 \frac{\sqrt 2}{2(x\pm\sqrt2/2)^2 + 1}dx \\
&= \tan^{-1}(x\sqrt 2 \pm 1)\bigg|^S_0\\
&= \tan^{-1}(S\sqrt 2 \pm 1) \mp \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*} So unraveling all of this using logarithm rules, we have \begin{align*} I^* &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\bigg(\frac 1 2\log(S^2 + S\sqrt 2 + 1) - \frac 1 2\log(S^2 - S\sqrt 2 + 1) \\ &\hspace{4cm} + \tan^{-1}(S\sqrt2 + 1) + \tan^{-1}(S\sqrt 2 - 1) \bigg)\\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left(\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{S^2 + S\sqrt 2 + 1}{S^2 - S\sqrt 2 + 1}} \right) +\tan^{-1}(S\sqrt2 + 1) + \tan^{-1}(S\sqrt 2 - 1) \right)\end{align*} and thus $$\boxed{I = 1 - \frac{1}{2S\sqrt2}\left(\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{S^2 + S\sqrt 2 + 1}{S^2 - S\sqrt 2 + 1}} \right) +\tan^{-1}(S\sqrt2 + 1) + \tan^{-1}(S\sqrt 2 - 1)\right)}$$ where $\boxed{S = s^{-1/4}(R_x + R_c).}$

And now I leave it to you to check this answer; it's highly possible I made algebra mistakes along the way.

EDIT: pointed out by Claude Leibovici in the comments, using the arctangent addition identity $\tan^{-1}(a) + \tan^{-1}(b) = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{a+b}{1-ab}\right)$, we can further simplify $$\boxed{I = 1 - \frac{1}{2S\sqrt2}\left(\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{S^2 + S\sqrt 2 + 1}{S^2 - S\sqrt 2 + 1}} \right) +\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{S \sqrt 2}{1-S^2}\right) \right)}$$

Comment: Well done ! You can combine $\tan^{-1}(S\sqrt2 + 1) + \tan^{-1}(S\sqrt 2 - 1)$ as $\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} S}{1-S^2}\right)$. Then $+1$.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your time. Still trying to understand though, but seems right to me... (Can't understand why someone has downvoted the question as this is related to the problem of my research. I am not a mathematician but and engineer trying to develop analysis of my model)

Comment: @User8128: Can I use your solution in my research article (i.e. if everything goes right with my model.). Note that this is only a part of the bigger picture I am trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

After User8128's answer, assuming that you enjoy complex numbers, let $a,b,c,d$ to be the roots of $x^4+1=0$ and write $x^4+1=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$.

Using partial fraction decomposition, we then have
$$\frac 1{x^4+1}=\frac{1}{(a-b) (a-c) (a-d) (x-a)}+\frac{1}{(b-a) (b-c) (b-d) (x-b)}+\frac{1}{(c-a) (c-b) (c-d) (x-c)}+\frac{1}{(d-a)
   (d-b) (d-c) (x-d)}$$ that is to say
$$\frac 1{x^4+1}=\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac {k_i}{x-t_i}\implies I=\int \frac {dx}{x^4+1}=\sum_{i=1}^4 k_i\log(x-t_i)$$

Replacing and recombining, you will end with two logarithms and two arctangents which can be recombined into one logarithm and one arctangent.

$$I=\frac 1{4\sqrt 2}\log \left(\frac{x^2+\sqrt{2} x+1}{x^2-\sqrt{2} x+1}\right)+\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x\sqrt{2} }{1-x^2}\right)$$
as already given by User8128.